# Where do I put downloaded .tar.gz files?

Tags: pi-3

I have downloaded a .tar.gz file to my Windows computer.
I am connected to my Raspberry Pi 3 using mobaXterm.
I've opened a terminal session and have access to my Pi.

1. Where do I place a copy of the .tar.gz file on the Pi?
2. How do I un-zip & install it?

Any help would be great & thanks!

Comment: You can't un-zip a tar file. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store files on your Pi file system anywhere you have permissions.  If you are not root, then typical places are your home directory, directories and sub-directories you create from your home directory and ... the /tmp directory.  Note that /tmp will be erased on reboot.

If the file is an installation image or some other media that you wish to extract and install, I would suggest downloading and extracting to /tmp and extract there.  To extract a .tar.gz file, you can run:

`tar -xvzf <filename>.tar.gz`

(see also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/25347/what-command-do-i-need-to-unzip-extract-a-tar-gz-file).

As for installing a downloaded and extracted package, that will usually vary based upon the nature of the package.  You may want to see if the package is also available for `apt-get` download and installation.

Comment: While I don't think current versions of Raspbian do this by default, `/tmp` maybe a tmpfs (i.e. RAM based) mount point and unpacking a large archive in it may fail and cause problems for software that need the space.  To check, `mount | grep "/tmp"`.  If this mentions tmpfs, create a directory somewhere on the actual SD card instead (e.g., `$HOME`).  If it says nothing you are okay.  Also beware that `/tmp` may or may not be cleared by the OS on reboot regardless of its nature.

Comment: Being kinda new at this and little experience, the easy answers are not always obvious to me. Thanks for the assistance! The answer was in the apt-get function.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you may put said tarball anywhere you like. Welcome to the freedom Linux has to offer ;) If it is some software to run I'd go with `/opt` (it might be necessary to gain elevated privileges to have write access there). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) to find out which directory would serve your needs best.

Untar using this command (as pointed out by Goldilocks, it might be advisable to create an empty directory first and do the dirty works in there in case the tar does not politely unfold into a new directory itself):

```
tar xfa blub.tar.gz
```

See also our [blog](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/142634263599/improving-your-command-line-skills-part-3) to learn more useful things to get you started with the Pi.

Comment: Beware while most tar files, like zips, should politely unfold into a new directory, they might not, so unless you have a way to examine them first you may want to create an empty directory and do it in there.

Comment: I like it when they do that ;) and mingle their files and directories with whatever was already there.

Comment: Yes it is like being served food without a plate, standing up.